# Stored procedure times out in DBML, but is otherwise instant

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I've written a simple stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2, that executes instantly, when testing in SSMS. However, when I map it to LINQ2SQL (DBML) and execute it there, it times out for some reason.

I haven't the slightest where to begin on this...

EDIT: Everything else works (general LINQ2SQL as well as other sprocs). The sproc mentioned below was newly added to DBML.

Sproc:

```
SELECT TOP 50 P.ID, t1.NAME
FROM P
INNER JOIN t1 ON P.ID = t1.ID
WHERE (P.ID <> @id) AND (P.ID2 = @id2) AND t1.NAME IN (
    select NAME from t1
    where ID = @id
)
```

C#:

```
    int id1,id2;
    using (var db = new DataContext())
    {
        foreach (var item in db.SPROC(ID1, ID2)) // Timeout exception here!
        {
            // code...
        }
    }
```

**EDIT #2:** I've altered the sproc to the same exact code, and now it works. I'm not sure what was the problem, but I'm assuming it wasn't SQL Server's fault.

Comment: Check the connection string, does it point to the same server as the SSMS? does it use the same port?

Comment: @AlexandrMihalciuc other sproces and linq2sql work just fine

Comment: Can you capture the generated request in sql profiler?

Comment: I don't have SQL profiler installed. Are there other ways?

Comment: Here is free profiler https://sites.google.com/site/sqlprofiler/